# Is there a plot style for PolarPlot to look like matlab polar()?

Tags: plotting, ticks

The plot style of Matlab's polar function

[image: polar plot]

appears to be pretty conventional for antenna radiation patterns in the references I'm looking at (sometimes with tick markings that count +- from the theta = 0 direction)

The basic plot can be done easily enough with Mathematica:

```
PolarPlot[ Cos[2 t] Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

but doesn't have the circular and arc scales, nor angular tick markings.  Those probably wouldn't be hard to add with Epilog, but I was wondering if there's already an option to do this easily in Mathematica without writing a bunch of code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly,

```
PolarPlot[Cos[2 t] Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, .5}, 
  PolarGridLines -> Automatic, PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarTicks -> {Table[{N[Pi/6 i], ToString[30 i] <> "°"}, {i, 0, 11}], 
    Table[{0.1 i, 0.1 i}, {i, 4}]}]
```

produces the desired results.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If "tick markings that count +- from the theta = 0 direction" are desired, replace the first `Table` in the code just above by

```
Table[{N[Pi/6 i], ToString[Abs[30 Mod[i, 12, -6]]] <> "°"}, {i, 0, 11}]
```